# How to notate harmonic sequences in roman numerals analysis in main theme from Beethoven Symphony 7 2nd movement Alegretto?

Tags: analysis, roman-numerals

### Q1: How would you notate the first four bars of the second system?

I'm trying to understand the introductory theme from the Alegretto in Beethoven's 7th Symphony. Here's what I have so far, which doesn't seem right in the first four bars of the 2nd system.

[image: First two systems]

#### Q2: Is there a standard way to annotate harmonic sequences like ↓4↑M3<sup>(6)</sup>?

There's a sequence at the beginning of the second system. To me this sounds like a portion of a "down a fourth up a minor third" descending sequence pattern, using inversions to make a chromatically descending bassline, except that the starting chord is e minor instead of E major as notated here (please forgive my musescore skills, I wouldn't normally place the accidentals this way).

[image: down a fourth, up a minor third chord pattern descending from E5 to E4 with a chromatic bassline due to the 1st inversions]

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Q1:**

Beat 2.5 of the 3rd bar of System 2 is a **vii°6 chord**, a dominant-function chord. It resolves to I(!) and is therefore **not passing**.

Also note that the first 2 bars and the next 2 bars of System 2 both try to pull off a localized I-i chord progression (the first time between the 2nd and 3rd bars, the second time within the 4th bar). Outright saying that the 2nd and 3rd bars of System 2 are just Em: V into A: ii - vii°6 isn't telling the whole story.